# Zoom option is not working for google map

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

i am using google map api for the development in the map options i am setting the zoom level of map but there is no change in view

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head lang="en">
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        var markers = [{
            "title": 'point4',
            "lat": '1.355333',
            "lng": '103.987305',
            "description": 'uuu'
        }, {
            "title": 'point3',
            "lat": '1.354432',
            "lng": '103.987262',
            "description": 'zzz'
        },  {
            "title": 'point3',
            "lat": '1.354432',
            "lng": '103.987262',
            "description": 'zzz'
        },{
            "title": 'point3',
            "lat": '1.353199',
            "lng": '103.986908',
            "description": 'zzz'
        },{
            "title": 'point3',
            "lat": '1.353199',
            "lng": '103.986908',
            "description": 'zzz'
        }, {
            "title": 'point4',
            "lat": '1.352389',
            "lng": '103.986538',
            "description": 'zzz'
        },{
            "title": 'point1',
            "lat": '1.353751',
            "lng": '103.986688',
            "description": 'xxxx'
        }, {
            "title": 'point2',
            "lat": '1.352657',
            "lng": '103.986184',
            "description": 'yyyy'
        }, {
            "title": 'point3',
            "lat": '1.352657',
            "lng": '103.986184',
            "description": 'zzz'
        }, {
            "title": 'point4',
            "lat": '1.351477',
            "lng": '103.985701',
            "description": 'uuu'
        }, {
            "title": 'point4',
            "lat": '1.351477',
            "lng": '103.985701',
            "description": 'uuu'
        }, {
            "title": 'point4',
            "lat": '1.350265',
            "lng": '103.985165',
            "description": 'uuu'
        }];
        var gmarkers = [];
        var colorVariable = ["yellow", "green", "red", "saffron","yellow", "green", "red","yellow", "green", "red"];
        var map;
        var degree = 0;
        function autoRotate() {
            var $elie = $("#dvMap");
            degree = degree + 65;
            rotate(degree);
            function rotate(degree) {
                // For webkit browsers: e.g. Chrome
                $elie.css({ WebkitTransform: 'rotate(' + degree + 'deg)'});
                $elie.css({ '-moz-transform': 'rotate(' + degree + 'deg)'});
                $elie.css({ '-ms-transform': 'rotate(' + degree + 'deg)'});
                $elie.css({ '-o-transform': 'rotate(' + degree + 'deg)'});

                for (var i= 0; i < gmarkers.length; i++) {
                    gmarkers[i].setIcon(icon48.png("red", -degree));
                }
            }
        }
        window.onload = function() {
            var mapOptions = {
                center: new google.maps.LatLng(markers[0].lat, markers[0].lng),
                zoom: 15,
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
                heading: 90,
                tilt: 45,
                styles: [
                    {
                        "featureType": "poi",
                        "stylers": [
                            { "visibility": "off" }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            };

            map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("dvMap"), mapOptions);
            var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
            var lat_lng = new Array();
            var latlngbounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
            for (i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
                var data = markers[i]
                var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(data.lat, data.lng);
                lat_lng.push(myLatlng);
                var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    position: myLatlng,
                    map: map,
                    icon:'icon48.png',
                    title: data.title
                });
                latlngbounds.extend(marker.position);
                (function(marker, data) {
                    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", function(e) {
                        infoWindow.setContent(data.description);
                        infoWindow.open(map, marker);
                    });
                })(marker, data);
                gmarkers.push(marker);
            }
            map.setCenter(latlngbounds.getCenter());
            map.fitBounds(latlngbounds);


            //Loop and Draw Path Route between the Points on MAP
            for (var i = 0; i < lat_lng.length; i++) {
                var src = lat_lng[i];
                var des = lat_lng[i + 1];
                var k=i;
                i=i+1;
                getDirections(src, des, colorVariable[k], map);

            }
            /*autoRotate();*/
        }

        function getDirections(src, des, color, map) {
            //Intialize the Direction Service
            var service = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
            service.route({
                origin: src,
                destination: des,
                travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.DRIVING
            }, function(result, status) {
                if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
                    //Intialize the Path Array
                    var path = [];
                    for (var i = 0; i < result.routes[0].overview_path.length; i++) {
                        path.push(result.routes[0].overview_path[i]);
                    }
                    //Set the Path Stroke Color
                    var polyOptions = {
                        strokeColor: color,
                        strokeOpacity: 1.0,
                        strokeWeight: 8,
                        path: path,
                        map: map
                    }
                    poly = new google.maps.Polyline(polyOptions);
                    poly.setMap(map);

                }
            });
        }

        function pinSymbol(color, rotation) {
            return {
                path: 'M 0,0 C -2,-20 -10,-22 -10,-30 A 10,10 0 1,1 10,-30 C 10,-22 2,-20 0,0 z',
                fillColor: color,
                fillOpacity: 1,
                strokeColor: '#000',
                strokeWeight: 1,
                rotation: rotation,
                scale: 1
            };
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="dvMap" style="width:1000px;height:1000px"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

I tried to explicitly set the option has map.setZoom(15); 
and i tired to set the preserve Viewport option of the map to true  no luck please help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the call to `map.fitBounds` if you want to control the zoom level of the map.  The [google.maps.Map.fitBounds method](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#Map) zooms and centers the map on its argument (a google.maps.LatLngBounds object).

> **fitBounds**(bounds:LatLngBounds|LatLngBoundsLiteral)
>
> Return Value:  None
>
> Sets the viewport to contain the given bounds.

Then set the center and zoom level of the map to whatever you desire.

**code snippet:**

```js
var gmarkers = [];
var colorVariable = ["yellow", "green", "red", "saffron", "yellow", "green", "red", "yellow", "green", "red"];
var map;
var degree = 0;

function autoRotate() {
  var $elie = $("#dvMap");
  degree = degree + 65;
  rotate(degree);

  function rotate(degree) {
    // For webkit browsers: e.g. Chrome
    $elie.css({
      WebkitTransform: 'rotate(' + degree + 'deg)'
    });
    $elie.css({
      '-moz-transform': 'rotate(' + degree + 'deg)'
    });
    $elie.css({
      '-ms-transform': 'rotate(' + degree + 'deg)'
    });
    $elie.css({
      '-o-transform': 'rotate(' + degree + 'deg)'
    });

    for (var i = 0; i < gmarkers.length; i++) {
      gmarkers[i].setIcon(icon48.png("red", -degree));
    }
  }
}
window.onload = function() {
  var mapOptions = {
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(markers[0].lat, markers[0].lng),
    zoom: 15,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
    heading: 90,
    tilt: 45,
    styles: [{
      "featureType": "poi",
      "stylers": [{
        "visibility": "off"
      }]
    }]
  };

  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("dvMap"), mapOptions);
  var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
  var lat_lng = new Array();
  var latlngbounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
  for (i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
    var data = markers[i]
    var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(data.lat, data.lng);
    lat_lng.push(myLatlng);
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: myLatlng,
      map: map,
      icon: 'icon48.png',
      title: data.title
    });
    latlngbounds.extend(marker.position);
    (function(marker, data) {
      google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", function(e) {
        infoWindow.setContent(data.description);
        infoWindow.open(map, marker);
      });
    })(marker, data);
    gmarkers.push(marker);
  }
  map.setCenter(latlngbounds.getCenter());

  //Loop and Draw Path Route between the Points on MAP
  for (var i = 0; i < lat_lng.length; i++) {
    var src = lat_lng[i];
    var des = lat_lng[i + 1];
    var k = i;
    i = i + 1;
    getDirections(src, des, colorVariable[k], map);

  }
  /*autoRotate();*/
}

function getDirections(src, des, color, map) {
  //Intialize the Direction Service
  var service = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
  service.route({
    origin: src,
    destination: des,
    travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.DRIVING
  }, function(result, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
      //Intialize the Path Array
      var path = [];
      for (var i = 0; i < result.routes[0].overview_path.length; i++) {
        path.push(result.routes[0].overview_path[i]);
      }
      //Set the Path Stroke Color
      var polyOptions = {
        strokeColor: color,
        strokeOpacity: 1.0,
        strokeWeight: 8,
        path: path,
        map: map
      }
      poly = new google.maps.Polyline(polyOptions);
      poly.setMap(map);

    }
  });
}

function pinSymbol(color, rotation) {
  return {
    path: 'M 0,0 C -2,-20 -10,-22 -10,-30 A 10,10 0 1,1 10,-30 C 10,-22 2,-20 0,0 z',
    fillColor: color,
    fillOpacity: 1,
    strokeColor: '#000',
    strokeWeight: 1,
    rotation: rotation,
    scale: 1
  };
}
var markers = [{
  "title": 'point4',
  "lat": '1.355333',
  "lng": '103.987305',
  "description": 'uuu'
}, {
  "title": 'point3',
  "lat": '1.354432',
  "lng": '103.987262',
  "description": 'zzz'
}, {
  "title": 'point3',
  "lat": '1.354432',
  "lng": '103.987262',
  "description": 'zzz'
}, {
  "title": 'point3',
  "lat": '1.353199',
  "lng": '103.986908',
  "description": 'zzz'
}, {
  "title": 'point3',
  "lat": '1.353199',
  "lng": '103.986908',
  "description": 'zzz'
}, {
  "title": 'point4',
  "lat": '1.352389',
  "lng": '103.986538',
  "description": 'zzz'
}, {
  "title": 'point1',
  "lat": '1.353751',
  "lng": '103.986688',
  "description": 'xxxx'
}, {
  "title": 'point2',
  "lat": '1.352657',
  "lng": '103.986184',
  "description": 'yyyy'
}, {
  "title": 'point3',
  "lat": '1.352657',
  "lng": '103.986184',
  "description": 'zzz'
}, {
  "title": 'point4',
  "lat": '1.351477',
  "lng": '103.985701',
  "description": 'uuu'
}, {
  "title": 'point4',
  "lat": '1.351477',
  "lng": '103.985701',
  "description": 'uuu'
}, {
  "title": 'point4',
  "lat": '1.350265',
  "lng": '103.985165',
  "description": 'uuu'
}];
```

```css
html,
body,
#dvMap {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<div id="dvMap"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

i have tried like this check once it's working by setZoom() why your not getting because your setting bounds so after bounds setup zoom changing related to bounds,if you want all markers at zoom level 15 then don't set bounds,if not can you tell me where you want set zoom exactly...

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head lang="en">
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    var markers = [{
        "title": 'point4',
        "lat": '1.355333',
        "lng": '103.987305',
        "description": 'uuu'
    }, {
        "title": 'point3',
        "lat": '1.354432',
        "lng": '103.987262',
        "description": 'zzz'
    },  {
        "title": 'point3',
        "lat": '1.354432',
        "lng": '103.987262',
        "description": 'zzz'
    },{
        "title": 'point3',
        "lat": '1.353199',
        "lng": '103.986908',
        "description": 'zzz'
    },{
        "title": 'point3',
        "lat": '1.353199',
        "lng": '103.986908',
        "description": 'zzz'
    }, {
        "title": 'point4',
        "lat": '1.352389',
        "lng": '103.986538',
        "description": 'zzz'
    },{
        "title": 'point1',
        "lat": '1.353751',
        "lng": '103.986688',
        "description": 'xxxx'
    }, {
        "title": 'point2',
        "lat": '1.352657',
        "lng": '103.986184',
        "description": 'yyyy'
    }, {
        "title": 'point3',
        "lat": '1.352657',
        "lng": '103.986184',
        "description": 'zzz'
    }, {
        "title": 'point4',
        "lat": '1.351477',
        "lng": '103.985701',
        "description": 'uuu'
    }, {
        "title": 'point4',
        "lat": '1.351477',
        "lng": '103.985701',
        "description": 'uuu'
    }, {
        "title": 'point4',
        "lat": '1.350265',
        "lng": '103.985165',
        "description": 'uuu'
    }];
    var gmarkers = [];
    var colorVariable = ["yellow", "green", "red", "saffron","yellow",    "green", "red","yellow", "green", "red"];
    var map;
    var degree = 0;
    function autoRotate() {
        var $elie = $("#dvMap");
        degree = degree + 65;
        rotate(degree);
        function rotate(degree) {
            // For webkit browsers: e.g. Chrome
            $elie.css({ WebkitTransform: 'rotate(' + degree + 'deg)'});
            $elie.css({ '-moz-transform': 'rotate(' + degree + 'deg)'});
            $elie.css({ '-ms-transform': 'rotate(' + degree + 'deg)'});
            $elie.css({ '-o-transform': 'rotate(' + degree + 'deg)'});

            for (var i= 0; i < gmarkers.length; i++) {
                gmarkers[i].setIcon(icon48.png("red", -degree));
            }
        }
    }

    window.onload = function() {
        var mapOptions = {
            center: new google.maps.LatLng(markers[0].lat, markers[0].lng),
            zoom: 10,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
            heading: 90,
            tilt: 45,
            styles: [
                {
                    "featureType": "poi",
                    "stylers": [
                        { "visibility": "off" }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        };

        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("dvMap"),     mapOptions);
        var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
        var lat_lng = new Array();
        console.log(map.getZoom());
        var latlngbounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
        for (i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
            var data = markers[i]
            var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(data.lat, data.lng);
            lat_lng.push(myLatlng);
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: myLatlng,
                map: map,
                icon:'icon48.png',
                title: data.title
            });
            latlngbounds.extend(marker.position);
            (function(marker, data) {
                google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", function(e) {
                    infoWindow.setContent(data.description);
                    infoWindow.open(map, marker);
                });
            })(marker, data);
            gmarkers.push(marker);
        }
        map.setZoom(15);
        console.log(map.getZoom());
        map.setCenter(latlngbounds.getCenter());
        map.fitBounds(latlngbounds);
        map.addListener('zoom_changed', function() {
            console.log(map.getZoom());
        });


        //Loop and Draw Path Route between the Points on MAP
        for (var i = 0; i < lat_lng.length; i++) {
            var src = lat_lng[i];
            var des = lat_lng[i + 1];
            var k=i;
            i=i+1;
            getDirections(src, des, colorVariable[k], map);

        }
        /*autoRotate();*/
    }

    function getDirections(src, des, color, map) {
        //Intialize the Direction Service
        var service = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
        service.route({
            origin: src,
            destination: des,
            travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.DRIVING
        }, function(result, status) {
            if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
                //Intialize the Path Array
                var path = [];
                for (var i = 0; i < result.routes[0].overview_path.length;    i++) {
                    path.push(result.routes[0].overview_path[i]);
                }
                //Set the Path Stroke Color
                var polyOptions = {
                    strokeColor: color,
                    strokeOpacity: 1.0,
                    strokeWeight: 8,
                    path: path,
                    map: map
                }
                poly = new google.maps.Polyline(polyOptions);
                poly.setMap(map);

            }
        });
    }

    function pinSymbol(color, rotation) {
        return {
            path: 'M 0,0 C -2,-20 -10,-22 -10,-30 A 10,10 0 1,1 10,-30 C 10,-22 2,-20 0,0 z',
            fillColor: color,
            fillOpacity: 1,
            strokeColor: '#000',
            strokeWeight: 1,
            rotation: rotation,
            scale: 1
        };
    }
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="dvMap" style="width:1000px;height:1000px"></div>
</body>
</html>
```